# Responsive echart-for-reacts height

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to create a chart with echarts-for-react js. Here is my code

```
import ReactECharts from "echarts-for-react";
import "./App.css";
import "./index.css";

function App() {
  const x = [1, 2, 3];
  const y = [2, 3, 9];
  const color = "black";
  const option = {
    xAxis: {
      type: "category",
      data: x,
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: "value",
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "axis",
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: y,
        type: "line",
        smooth: true,
        itemStyle: {
          opacity: 0,
          color: "black",
        },
        lineStyle: {
          color: "black",
        },
      },
    ],
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="aspect-[1920/1080] w-full font-red flex justify-center items-center">
        <div className="aspect-[413/280] w-[50%] bg-[lightblue]">
          {" "}
          <ReactECharts option={option} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "tes2",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "echarts": "^5.4.3",
    "echarts-for-react": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
}
```

I want the chart's ratio to be [413/280], so that when I resize the page using scroll up / down, the chart ratio not changes. That's why I'm using aspect-ratio and w-[50%] on the code

But it seems that the height of the chart is not fixed. When I use the scroll up/down, the height of the charts changes so it makes the chart's ratio broken. Is there any way I can fix this?

Here is the original charts
[image: before scrolling]

Here is the charts after I scroll the mouse
[image: after scrolling]

Thank you for the help!